# why code change does not trigger transpile?

Tags: typescript

I have a dialog flow application with my fulfillment setup using a typescript backend.  I started from a project template so had the whole preconfigured bit going and didn't worry myself with the details.

Working in VS Code and never explictly bulid. I've been using the firebase deploy command which is configured to do the build et. al.

Now my problem is that I tried to add a code change and it's not causing the js to get transpiled when I make the change.  I have not noticed this (nor checked for it, it presumably was, though) before.

I basically changed a hard coded string to a property.

```
const app = dialogflow(
    {
        debug: true,
        clientId:"xxxx"
    }
);
```

to

```
import * as appConfig from '../config.json';
const app = dialogflow(
    {
        debug: true,
        clientId:appConfig.actionsClientId
    }
);
```

If I change "xxxx" to "yyyy" and manually build, i get fresh .js.
If I change "xxxx" to appConfig.actionsClientId it doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tsconfig file and also refer to the [official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html)

Comment: Anything in particular I should be looking for?